# Why do exponential factors lead to divergent series approximations, instead of to wrong convergent results?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, divergent-series

According to [The Devil's Invention](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1006145903624) by Boyd we have

> **PROPOSITION 2** (Exponential Reciprocal Rule). If a function f(ε) contains a
>   term which is an exponential function of the reciprocal of ε, then a power series in
>   ε will not converge to f(ε).

The problem is, of course, that factors like $exp(−q/ε)$ are invisible to the usual perturbative approach: $exp(−q/ε) ∼ 0 + 0ε + 0ε^2 +\ldots$

This immediately means that if we try to approximate a function like $$  h(ε) ≡ \sqrt{1 + ε} + exp(−1/ε)$$
with a series, this series will converge for $|ε| < 1$, but to a wrong value for all $ε$ except $ε = 0$.

So far, so good.

My problem is understanding why "*this situation – a convergent series for a function that contains a term exponentially small in 1/ε, and therefore invisible to the power series – seems to be rare in applications.*"([The Devil's Invention](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1006145903624) by Boyd)

Instead, usually a factor like $exp(−1/ε)$ leads to a divergent series. If we try to approximate it with the usual methods, we get a good approximation, but only up to some fixed order $\sim O(1/\epsilon)$.

Is there some easy example or good way to see why and how such factors that are invisible to the usual series approach can lead to a divergent series? And if yes, why does this divergence start at $\sim O(1/\epsilon)$?